# Подключение Nest.js к базе данных MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

Как исправить ошибку "MissingDriverError: Wrong driver: "undefined" given" при подключении к базе данных MySQL через TypeORM в Nest.js? Установил драйвер mysql через yarn и прописал его в AppModule, однако при запуске приложения ошибка все равно возникает. Как можно решить данную проблему?

ormconfig.json - подключение к базе данных

```
{
    "type": "mysql",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 3306,
    "username": "root",
    "password": "0451",
    "database": "db_curators",
    "entities": ["src/**/*.entity.ts"],
    "synchronize": true
  }
```

app.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Curator } from './curator/curator.entity';
import { CuratorController } from './curator/curator.controller';
import { CuratorService } from './curator/curator.service';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRoot(), TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Curator])],
  controllers: [CuratorController],
  providers: [CuratorService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

curator.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Curator } from './curator.entity';

@Injectable()
export class CuratorService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Curator)
    private curatorRepository: Repository<Curator>,
  ) {}

  async findAll(): Promise<Curator[]> {
    return this.curatorRepository.find();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка "MissingDriverError: Wrong driver: "undefined" given" может возникнуть, если TypeORM не может определить, какой драйвер базы данных использовать. В вашем случае, вы указали настройки подключения в ormconfig.json, однако не передали их в TypeOrmModule.forRoot().

Чтобы исправить эту ошибку, вам нужно передать настройки подключения к базе данных в метод TypeOrmModule.forRoot(). Вы можете сделать это, обновив ваш AppModule следующим образом:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Curator } from './curator/curator.entity';
import { CuratorController } from './curator/curator.controller';
import { CuratorService } from './curator/curator.service';
import { Connection } from 'typeorm'; // импортируем Connection

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,
      username: 'root',
      password: '0451',
      database: 'db_curators',
      entities: [Curator], // изменяем на массив из объектов сущностей
      synchronize: true,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Curator])
  ],
  controllers: [CuratorController],
  providers: [CuratorService],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private connection: Connection) {} // создаем конструктор с параметром Connection
}
```

Обратите внимание на изменения в объекте настроек TypeOrmModule.forRoot(). В частности, явно указано, что сущность Curator находится в файле curator.entity.ts. Кроме того, в конструкторе AppModule мы получаем параметр Connection, который нужен для устранения ошибки "Cannot read property 'query' of undefined". Если вы все еще столкнулись с этой ошибкой, вам нужно обновить app.module.ts, как показано выше, и затем в каждом сервисе, который использует Repository, добавить в конструктор параметр Connection.

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository, Connection } from 'typeorm'; // импортируем Connection
import { Curator } from './curator.entity';

@Injectable()
export class CuratorService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Curator)
    private curatorRepository: Repository<Curator>,
    private connection: Connection // добавляем параметр Connection в конструктор
  ) {}

  async findAll(): Promise<Curator[]> {
    return this.connection.manager.find(Curator); // используем Connection вместо this.curatorRepository
  }
}
```